# How to address the error "MBUF: error setting mempool handler" seen with DPDK 20.11

Tags: dpdk

I did a static linking of libdpdk to my application and when I start the application EAL init fails.

Logs:

```
EAL: Detected 80 lcore(s)
EAL: Detected 2 NUMA nodes
EAL: Detected static linkage of DPDK
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'VA'
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: No legacy callbacks, legacy socket not created
MBUF: error setting mempool handler
EAL: Error - exiting with code: 1
  Cause: Cannot init packet mbuf pool Invalid argument
```

I installed DPDK-20.11 in my test server, using the following commands.

```
# meson build
#cd build
#ninja ; ninja install
```

I built my application Makefile taking l2fwd Makefile as an example, not sure what I am missing.

Looking out for suggestions.

[Edit-1]

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{ 

int ret; unsigned lcore_id; 

ret = rte_eal_init(argc, argv); 
if (ret < 0) 
rte_panic("Cannot init EAL\n"); 

struct rte_mempool *mp = 
rte_pktmbuf_pool_create("packet_pool", 8192, 64, 0, RTE_MBUF_DEFAULT_BUF_SIZE, rte_socket_id()); 

return 0;
}
```

How to build

1. copy makefile from l2fwd to custom app folder
2. execute `make static`
3. run the application `sudo ./a.out`

Comment: can you please sahred the following information `1) have you used make or make static for l2fwd examples? 2) can you perform ls -lal [dpdk root folder]/examples/l2fwd/build? 3) can you share the cmd line used? 4) can you update ticket with running --log-level=8`

Comment: Vipin, I meant for my application I took l2fwd's makefile as an example.

Comment: I will humbly ask you to share your simple code snippet to reproduce the error. This is to reproduce the error and isolate if it is from Makefile or your custom app.

Comment: Vipin , Apologize for the short response earlier, (before I could complete the response I hit enter by mistake). I built using make static. With log level 8, I don't see any new logs ```EAL: Detected 80 lcore(s)
EAL: Detected 2 NUMA nodes
EAL: Detected static linkage of DPDK
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'VA'
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: No legacy callbacks, legacy socket not created
MBUF: error setting mempool handler
EAL: Error - exiting with code: 1```

Comment: Code snippet  ```                                                                                                               int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int ret;
        unsigned lcore_id;

        ret = rte_eal_init(argc, argv);
        if (ret < 0)
                rte_panic("Cannot init EAL\n");

        struct rte_mempool *mp = rte_pktmbuf_pool_create("packet_pool", 8192, 64,
                                           0, RTE_MBUF_DEFAULT_BUF_SIZE,
                                           rte_socket_id());
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you share your update

Comment: I shared the code snippet and the updates above. Can I move this discussion to chat?

Comment: Ran the code shared by you, I still see the failure. ```# ./build/l2fwd
EAL: Detected 80 lcore(s)
EAL: Detected 2 NUMA nodes
EAL: Detected static linkage of DPDK
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'VA'
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: No legacy callbacks, legacy socket not created
MBUF: error setting mempool handler
PANIC in main():
Cannot init EAL

```

Comment: Then is something wrong by the way I built base DPDK-20.11 ? 
I downloaded dpdk-20.11 and ran the following commands 
```
1. untar dpdk-20.113
2. cd dpdk-stable-20.11.1/
3. Meson build
4. Cd build
5. Ninja 
6. Ninja install
```
Then in the custom application directory (which is outside DPDK folder)
```
1. export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig
2. Make
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233231/discussion-between-fernando-and-vipin-varghese).

Comment: may I request for skype or google hangout

Comment: please accept and upvote to close the ticket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EDIT-1] update from live debug

Target OS: CENTOS 7
DPDK version: 20.11.1

There are multiple reasons which were causing error

1. Installing Mellanox libverbs affects the cflags and ldflags for dpdk `libdpdk.pc`
2. DPDK 21.11.1 meson build `(meson -Dexamples=l2fwd build; ninja -C install)` does not match `l2fwd Makefile option of make static`
3. using pkg-config from the installed target was also incorrect.

To fix the error we edited /usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig/libdpdk.pc to include the static libraries under `-Wl,--whole-archive` and `-Wl,--no-whole-archive`

it works

```
#include <rte_cycles.h>
#include <rte_prefetch.h>
#include <rte_lcore.h>
#include <rte_per_lcore.h>
#include <rte_branch_prediction.h>
#include <rte_interrupts.h>
#include <rte_random.h>
#include <rte_debug.h>
#include <rte_ether.h>
#include <rte_ethdev.h>
#include <rte_mempool.h>
#include <rte_mbuf.h>
#include <rte_string_fns.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

int ret; unsigned lcore_id;

ret = rte_eal_init(argc, argv);
if (ret < 0)
rte_panic("Cannot init EAL\n");

struct rte_mempool *mp =
rte_pktmbuf_pool_create("packet_pool", 8192, 64, 0, RTE_MBUF_DEFAULT_BUF_SIZE, rte_socket_id());
if (mp == NULL)
        rte_panic("Cannot init EAL\n");

printf("done!!!!!!!!!!!!");

return 0;
}
```

build: `sudo make static`

Output

```
$ sudo ./build/l2fwd
EAL: Detected 32 lcore(s)
EAL: Detected 2 NUMA nodes
EAL: Detected static linkage of DPDK
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'VA'
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
done!!!!!!!!!!!!
```